# Drop down value in filemaker database

Tags: database, filemaker

I have a drop down value which consists of two value Yes,No. All my payee lists gets updated if i choose yes and all my lists get updated to no if i choose no.I have one field only.I want the user to select of their choice.I don't want all the lists to be updated.

Comment: It sounds like the field in question is defined to have global storage. -- P.S. When you say *lists* you mean *records*, don't you?

Comment: might be not sure. how to declare it as global and allow user to select the drop down value?

Comment: You **don't** want it to have global storage: http://www.filemaker.com/13help/en/html/create_db.8.25.html#1029739

Comment: Similarly, if your drop down field is on a table that all of your records are related to, changing one value will change them all. (If, say, you are looking at a Portal of Invoice Line Items but your Yes/No flag is on the Invoices table)

Comment: Is the field that you have the yes/no value list attached to in the same payee table? Also, are the payee's showing in a portal?